# How to bypass loading screen in python requests?

Tags: python, html, http, python-requests

So I have a website, named example.com I am trying to send a requests too, when you load up the site on the browser there is a loading screen for maybe, 2 - 4 seconds (it is not captcha nor cloudflare) and then goes to the main page. In python I am trying to send a http get requests to that page but am met with the loading screen, is there anyway I can compelstely avoid that screen? Or atleast wait for the screen to pass then retrieve the response?

```
import requests 

response = requests.get(“example.com”)
print(response.text)
```

The desired response would be the main page, not the loading screen. I would like to refrain from using selenium, playwright or any browser emulation package, only as a last resort if there is **NO** possible way to bypass this simply with requests library.

Comment: Probably you have to analyze the JavaScript that loads the desired page and recreate its behavior in Python then.

Answer (score 1):

this should work.

```
import pyppeteer
import asyncio
pageurl = ""
async def main():
    # launches a chromium browser, can use chrome instead of chromium as well.
    browser = await pyppeteer.launch(headless=False)
    # creates a blank page
    page = await browser.newPage()
    # follows to the requested page and runs the dynamic code on the site.
    await page.goto(pageurl)
    # provides the html content of the page
    cont = await page.content()
    return cont

# prints the html code of the user profiel: tupac
print(asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main()))
```